# Jquery load data to div with settimeout

Tags: jquery, html, settimeout

I was wondering how I can load data every 10 seconds to the specified div '#load' without having to do the whole window.settimeout.

```
function load_data() {
  $(function() {
    var timer = 10000;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: strData,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#load').html(data);
            window.setTimeout("load_data()", timer);
        }
    });
 }); }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have to restructure the code a bit:

- You don't have to attach the Ajax call to `document.ready` every time you call the function. Make it vice versa.
- Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`.

Example:

```
$(function() {
    var timer = 10000;
    function load_data() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: strData,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#load').html(data);
                setTimeout(load_data, timer);
            }
        });
    }
    load_data();
    // or if you also want to defer the initial load:
    // setTimeout(load_data, timer);  
});
```

I don't understand why you want to avoid `setTimeout`.